# SSIS: Loop on multiple directories given in an Excel

Tags: excel, ssis

I have to read several input files of same structure and different origin with SSIS. These files are stored in multiple directories. Each directory contains multiple files that are related to a specific company location. The files are of same structure.

- Factory A --> file A, file B,...
- Factory B --> file C, file D,..

There is also an Excel with some details on Factory A and B. We plan to push the data to a SAP application and each file needs a specific accounting code depending on its location/factory, e.g.:

- Factory A, account 12345
- Factory A, account 54321

The idea was to first read the Excel line by line with the names of the factories and then do a For Each-Loop on each directory to read the files.

I managed to read a single directory by filling a variable with the directory name. E.g. I start with `gstrSubdir="Factory A"` and then do a simple Foreach-Loop on the subdirectory. So far, I am fine.

Now I need a loop that reads the first line of the Excel, sets the subdir variable, loops on the subdir and then reads the next line.

In principle I need to know how to do a nested For-Loop in SSIS without C#.

I hope my explanation is somehow understandable.

Would be more than happy to get some advice.

Regards,
Lars

Comment: Nested For loops are easy, just drag one loop into another loop. You'll probably want to load the Excel sheet into an ADO dataset, and then loop on that in the inner loop.

Comment: I was clear on how to drag one loop into the other. I just had no idea on the [ADO Enumerator thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9Uj_VGx1OM). That was the missing link. Thanks, @digital.aaron!

Comment: If you figure out the answer yourself, you're encouraged to post an answer to your own question. If you have more questions or need additional help, let me know and I can create a better explanation.